# How to write $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n}x^{n+1}$ in closed form or short form?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, closed-form

How to write $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n}x^{n+1}$ in closed form or short form?

We can write the above sum as

$\binom{0}{0}x+\binom{2}{1}x^2+\binom{4}{2}x^3+\binom{6}{3}x^4+\cdots+\binom{2N-2}{N-1}x^N$.

There is a formula $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^k$.

But how to apply it?

Is there any short form or any function that would give short form ?

Comment: (I wonder what do you expect.) See exercise 4 [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html), section 5.7.

Comment: See [OEIS A006134](https://oeis.org/A006134).

Comment: @metamorphy, I expect to introduce some kind of function like harmonic or hypergeometric functions and to make a compact or short form

Comment: @Henry, please see the changes in the question

Comment: Maple says it's 
$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-4x}}-\binom{2N}{N}x^{N+1}{}_{2}F_{1}(1,N+\frac{1}{2};N+1;4x)$

Comment: @Sil, are you saying this equal to $ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n}x^{n+1}$ ?  Can we get this by hand?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Yes, and I don't know, but there are people here which can do miracles with series, maybe they will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can transform using the duplication formula [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E5)
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n}x^{n+1}&=x\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{x^n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{(4x)^n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(4x)^n}{n!}\Gamma(n+1/2)-\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{(4x)^n}{n!}\Gamma(n+1/2)\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-4x}}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{(4x)^n}{n!}\Gamma(n+1/2)
\end{align}
from the [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem). Now, shifting the index in the sum,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{(4x)^n}{n!}\Gamma(n+1/2)&=\left( 4x \right)^N\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(4x)^k}{(N+k)!}\Gamma(N+k+1/2)\\
&=\left( 4x \right)^N\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(4x)^k}{k!}\frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(k+N+1/2)}{\Gamma(k+N+1)}\\
&=\left( 4x \right)^N\frac{\Gamma(N+1)}{\Gamma(N+1/2)}\,_2F_1\left( 1,N+1/2;N+1;4x) \right)
\end{align}
from the definition of the [hypergeometric function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.2.i). Finally, as noted by @Sil in the comment
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n}x^{n+1}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-4x}}- \binom{2N}{N}x^{N+1}\,_2F_1\left( 1,N+1/2;N+1;4x) \right)
\end{equation}

Comment: From your last equation, can you say whether the sum $\sum \binom{2n}{n}x^{n+1}$ can be rational number for some rational $x$ ? If so then what are they? What I can say that the first part $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$ can be rational for some particular $x$..

Comment: I am not sure to undertand the question as the lhs is clearly a rational number when $x$ is rational. BTW, you can express the hypergeometric function using [this representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0680.01) to retrieve the lhs.

Comment: Can you answer my this question-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390831/how-to-write-or-input-the-symbol-s-kn-x-inside-the-summation-sum-n-1n?noredirect=1#comment6975870_3390831. Please read the full question at least.