# How to write or input the symbol $S_k(N,x)$ inside the summation $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} x^n \sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u}n^u$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Suppose $S_k(N,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} n^{k+1}x^n$.

**Now I want to write or input the symbol** $S_k(N,x)$ inside the summation $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} x^n \sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u}n^u, \ \cdots \cdots (1)$.

I tried in the following way

$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} x^n \sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u}n^u \\ =\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{x^n}{n} \sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u}n^{u+1} \\ =\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{n} \right) \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n} x^n \sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u}n^{u+1} \right), \ \text{but this splitting it is not true} \\ =\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{n} \right) \left(\sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u} S_u(N,x) \right) \\
=H_n*\left(\sum_{u=0}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{u} S_u(N,x) \right), \ \text{where $H_n$ is harmonic number}$.

Thus since the splitting is not true, my method is wrong.

**Can you help in any other way to the term $S_k(N,x)$ into the expression $(1)$ ?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390691/how-to-write-sum-k-0l1-binoml1knk-or-n1l1-as-s?noredirect=1#comment6975826_3390691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  following  might be helpful. We have 
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S_k(N,x)}=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\binom{2n}{n}n^{k+1}x^n
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}&\binom{2n}{n}x^n\sum_{k=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{k}n^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\binom{2n}{n}n^kx^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{k}\color{blue}{S_{k-1}(N,x)}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we rearrange the sums to easier substitute $S_k(N,x)$.

**Supplement:** A relationship  between $S_k(N,x)$ and  $S_{k-1}(N,x)$

We have 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^x\frac{1}{t}\color{blue}{S_k(N,t)}\,dt&=\int_{0}^x\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\binom{2n}{n}n^{k+1}t^{n-1}\,dt\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\binom{2n}{n}n^{k+1}\int_{0}^xt^{n-1}\,dt\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\binom{2n}{n}n^kx^n\\
&=\color{blue}{S_{k-1}(N,x)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> Combining (1)  and (2) we can write
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}&\binom{2n}{n}x^n\sum_{k=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{k}n^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{k}S_{k-1}(N,x)\\
> &=\int_0^x\frac{1}{t}\sum_{k=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{k}\color{blue}{S_k(N,t)}\,dt
> \end{align*}

Comment: your answer is exactly correct, I also got that. However, for my purpose I need to input $S_k(N,x)$ not $S_{k-1}(N,x)$, otherwise some problem occurs to get my purpose. that is why I am trying to introduce new kind of function (like $H_n$) which will allow to input $S_k(N,x)$

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: Ok, I see.